# No option to add a 'featured image' in my wordpress installation

Tags: customization

Hay, I've installed WordPress 3 on my server, and duplicated the stock theme and made some amends to it. However, when i add a post, i don't see an option to add a 'featured image'. Has this featured been removed? How do i reactivate it?

Thanks

Comment: turned out the wordpress version was a little older than i thought! Its all working now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your theme must [indicate that it supports post thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails):

```
if ( function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
  // If not the standard size, state your size too
  set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200, false );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in 3. When you have a post or a page open, in a two-column view, it's on the right, down a bit.

If it's not there, you might see if the option to display it is unchecked in your screen options (upper right corner).